# Javascript RegEx extract all words as single matches but not numbers from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I extract each single word, but not the number, from this string in Javascript RegEx?

"10443 Sometown Somesuburb"

I don't want the number but want "Sometown" and "Somsuburb" as separate matches.

Comment: Then match using `/\b[a-zA-Z]+\b/g`

Comment: That's exactly what I was biting my fingernails off for. You're awesome!

I'd like to mark it as correct answer, but that doesn't seem to work on comments. Really, great Job!!!

Comment: I have added this as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex for your task:

```
/\b[a-zA-Z]+\b/g
```

to get only words containing letters for `match` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

`var newStr = "10443 Sometown Somesuburb".replace(/\d+\s*/g, "");`

Comment: \d will match unicode numbers as well you can use  [0-9] instead

Comment: That seems like an odd nitpick... But perhaps the requester wants all numbers, including Unicode